# Error on Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am using ToolBar of support library in my android app. I tried 2 hours to resolve this but i could not get success.

I have added ToolBar as a library in my project & v7 appcompat also

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="305dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar>
```

But my app is crashing by giving this log message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pes.user.pescoll/com.pes.user.pescoll.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
        at com.pes.user.pescoll.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pes.user.pescoll-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:240)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.pes.user.pescoll.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 22 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I am using in android studio tool

Would be helpful with some suggestion's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawer layout should not be inside the toolbar

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Amended answer, you will need to add a linear or relative layout around it.

Comment: You are using a wrong package for the Toolbar. The right package is. android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: @CodeChimp I applied your xml but it didnt work with me please can you check my question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000028/what-is-the-cause-of-error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar/33000231?noredirect=1#comment53826061_33000231

Comment: @Moudiz looking at your question I'd say it is something your missing on your imports.  I don't use Eclipse though so can't offer much more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added V7 library. so use toolbar from it.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

Comment: No i didnt add any library @shvet

Comment: I mean you have added Appcompat V7 so you will get toolbar from appcompat v7.