# what is the cause of error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.toolbar

Tags: android

I did read many SO question related to this error but none of them was related and helpful.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.i/com.example.i.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error
>   inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

this is my code I am implementing the toolbar

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initToolbars();
    }
    private void initToolbars() {

        Toolbar toolbarBottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
        toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch(item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_settings:
                        // TODO
                        break;
                    // TODO: Other cases
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        toolbarBottom.inflateMenu(R.menu.main);

    }
```

acitivity main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_above="@id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat if anyone need it

```
 Process: com.example.i, PID: 15385
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.i/com.example.i.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:340)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1973)
    at com.example.i.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
    ... 22 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr.toolbarStyle
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
```

screenshot of the library

[image]

and this is the imports I am using

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: the error is in the title .. ill added in the question

Comment: Please post a full stacktrace

Comment: you should add the stack trace and any relevant information in your question

Comment: you did not add the full stacktrace

Comment: @tyczj check now please

Comment: @moudiz look at ur libs folder what is the exact name of android support jar file ?

Comment: @Amalo check plz my edit I added a screenshot is it clear?

Comment: @Moudiz yes clear now plz try to remove the jar file from order import and export and copy and paste it into libs folder

Comment: Then clean project and run

Comment: how to remove the file ? I only can deselect it . in lib it exists the jar. I deselect it from order import and export and I run , I got the same error @Amalo

Comment: @Moudiz 
Please check your _AppTheme_ style,should have _Toolbar_style

Comment: You can remove it from libraries of exists

Comment: @pRaNaY where should I added ? in the layout ? and what should it contain ?

Comment: @Amalo ah you mean add it in folder directory? okay ill added

Comment: @Moudiz in your _style.xml_

Comment: @pRaNaY no I didnt add anything please tell me what should I add

Comment: @Amalo I did as you said , I did added in the lib workspace and removed from order import and export but still having the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the appcompat library

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'`

Comment: unfortuently I am using eclipse , I am using this imports 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: You need to add the appcompat library itself. The imports won't import anything if you don't have the library downloaded and installed in your project

Comment: check please my edit the screenshot ? is that what you mean ?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: yes I am doing it again, cleaning and refresh and closing eclipse then ill try again

Answer (score 0):

> you need to import this into your workspace:
>   androidsdk->extras->android->support->design
>
> Then go to the properties of this "design" project and check the "mark
>   it as library" option.
>
> After you are done with above points you can add this design project
>   to your own project.
>
> After that clean your project and everything should work then.

Comment: This solution is for eclipse, try once

Comment: can you explain more ? I have to go to eclipse ? or to sdk folder?

Comment: go to eclipse, go to File-> import -> Android->Existing android code into workspace. Navigate to the path  where your android sdk is located and then follow my answer